# Comparing models to pick the best one

Tags: r, model-comparison

I am trying to compare these 5 models but am unsure of which is best. Model 1 has the worst fit and model 5 has a p value above 0.05 so i have ruled these out. Im not sure if i should go on R-squared value alone. Would anyone be able to provide some help?

```r
 > mod_comparason
 # Comparison of Model Performance Indices

 Name |           Model |      AIC | AIC weights |      BIC | BIC weights |  RMSE | Sigma | R2 (cond.) | R2 (marg.) |   ICC |    R2 | R2 (adj.)
 mod1 |              lm | 1036.490 |     < 0.001 | 1045.697 |     < 0.001 | 6.182 | 6.221 |            |            |       | 0.362 |     0.358
 mod2 |              lm |  975.122 |     < 0.001 |  987.398 |       0.019 | 5.065 | 5.113 |            |            |       | 0.572 |     0.566
 mod3 |              lm |  958.629 |       0.984 |  998.525 |     < 0.001 | 4.544 | 4.726 |            |            |       | 0.655 |     0.629
 mod4 | lmerModLmerTest |  967.217 |       0.013 |  979.493 |       0.975 | 4.670 | 4.771 |      0.499 |      0.133 | 0.422 |       |          
 mod5 | lmerModLmerTest |  971.126 |       0.002 |  989.540 |       0.006 | 4.649 | 4.760 |      0.490 |      0.126 | 0.416 |       |
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to show us the models that you fitted, with more details, and tell us about context & background, and what is your goal?

Comment: I have added the models to the question. Model 1 is a simple linear model, 2 is a multiple regression model, 3 is a fixed effects model, 4 is a random intercept controlled on continent and 5 is a random slope controlled on continent. I am trying to find the best model in predicting Life expectancy here (so i think the model with the best fit).